# TLS .Net Applications, does it select based on connection or app?

Tags: c#, tls1.2

Ok, so, we have one of those famous TLS issues going on.   My question though is when does an app (or asmx in this case) elect what protocols to use?   For example, in our asmx, the first thing it tries to do is to look up some information in one of our local SQL servers, that hasn't been patched to allow TLSv1.2 yet.   It *looks* like it is using TLSv1.0 to handle that connection.   Then, it turns around and makes a call to an external web service, that is only allowing TLSv1.2 but fails.  It looks like the app has downgraded everything to using TLSv1.0 because of the SQL connection so when it gets to the external web service it fails to negotiate.

Sound about right?

If that's the case then, enabling TLSv1.2 on the SQL servers would be the best course of action, then everything would talk on TLSv1.2.

Just looking for conformation of my suspicions.
Thanks,
Nick

Comment: The application doesn't decide anything. The algorithm is negotiated per connection at the framework level. You can change the algorithm with connection string or runtime properties, but you can't use an unsupported version. TLS 1.2 was added with NET 4.5.2. Which .NET Framework version are you using?

Comment: Ok, maybe that's my problem.   Looks like everything was built with 4.5.1, which looks like it has TLS 1.2 included but not as a default.  4.5.2> must set it as a default first.

Comment: I went in and modified the web.configs to use 4.6.1 and then verified with WireShark.   Looks like it's using TLS 1.2 now.

Comment: 4.5.1 doesn't have TLS 1.2 at all.  4.5.2+ is an binary replacement though,  which is why you were able to simply change the version from the configuration